# Flattening quantification over relations

Tags: logic, isabelle

I have a Relation f defined as f: A -> B × C. I would like to write a firsr-order formula to constrain this relation to be a bijective function from A to B × C?

To be more precise, I would like the first order counter part of the following formula (actually conjunction of the three):

∀a: A, ∃! bc : B × C, f(a)=bc      `-- f is function`

∀a1,a2: A, f(a1)=f(a2) → a1=a2           `-- f is injective`

∀(b, c) : B × C, ∃ a : A, f(a)=bc       `-- f is surjective`

As you see the above formulae are in Higher Order Logic as I quantified over the relations. What is the first-order logic equivalent of these formulae if it is ever possible?

PS:
This is more general (math) question, rather than being more specific to any theorem prover, but for getting help from these communities --as I think there are mature understanding of mathematics in these communities-- I put the theorem provers tag on this question.

Comment: You might have better luck in the math forum: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Exchange because it's primarily a mathematics question; a more suitable forum is math.stackexchange.com.  The math tag on SO is for programming problems that have a substantively mathematical flavor.  They are at their heart though primarily a programming problem, not a mathematical problem.  You should post this question to a more suitable forum, and delete the question from this one.

Comment: I posted the question here, since it comes from the application area (I was trying to encode this in alloy. I posted this in alloy context but I did not get any response yet. So, I tried to abstract out the question in mathematical sense to get help from mathematical community specifically those who are working with theorem provers as they usually have good understanding of these type of questions.
(I am going to remove the math related keywords and keeping coq, issabelle)

Answer (score 1):

(**Update**: Someone's unhappy with my answer, and SO gets me fired up in general, so I say what I want here, and will probably delete it later, I suppose.

I understand that SO is not a place for debates and soapboxes. On the other hand, the OP, qartal, whom I assume is the unhappy one, wants to apply the answer from math.stackexchange.com, where ZFC sets dominates, to a question here which is tagged, at this moment, with `isabelle` and `logic`.

First, notation is important, and sloppy notation can result in a question that's ambiguous to the point of being meaningless.

Second, having a B.S. in math, I have full appreciation for the logic of ZFC sets, so I have full appreciation for math.stackexchange.com.

I make the argument here that the answer given on math.stackexchange.com, linked to below, is wrong in the context of Isabelle/HOL.  *(First hmmm, me making claims under ill-defined circumstances can be annoying to people.)*

If I'm wrong, and someone teaches me something, the situation here will be redeemed.

The answerer says this:

> First of all in logic `B x C` is just another set.

There's not just one logic. My immediate reaction when I see the symbol `x` is to think of a type, not a set. Consider this, which kind of looks like your `f: A -> BxC`:

```
definition foo :: "nat => int × real" where "foo x = (x,x)"
```

I guess I should be prolific in going back and forth between sets and types, and reading minds, but I did learn something by entering this term:

```
term "B × C" (* shows it's of type "('a × 'b) set" *)
```

Feeling paranoid, I did this to see if had fallen into a major gotcha:

```
term "f : A -> B × C"
```

It gives a syntax error. Here I am, getting all pedantic, and our discussion is ill-defined because the notation is ill-defined.

### The crux: the formula in the other answer is not first-order in this context

*(Another hmmm, after writing what I say below, I'm full circle. Saying things about stuff when the context of the stuff is ill-defined.)*

Context is everything. The context of the other site is generally ZFC sets. Here, it's HOL. That answerer says to assume these for his formula, wich I give below:

```
Ax is true iff x∈A
Bx is true iff x∈B×C
Rxy is true iff f(x)=y
```

Syntax. No one has defined it here, but the tag here is `isabelle`, so I take it to mean that I can substitute the left-hand side of the iff for the right-hand side.

Also, the expression `x ∈ A` **is** what would be in the formula in a typical set theory textbook, not `Rxy`. Therefore, for the answerer's formula to have meaning, I can rightfully insert `f(x) = y` into it.

This then is why I did a lot of hedging in my first answer. The variable `f` cannot be in the formula. If it's in the formula, then it's a free variable which is implicitly quantified. Here's the formula in Isar syntax:

```
term "∀x. (Ax --> (∃y. By ∧ Rxy ∧ (∀z. (Bz ∧ Rxz) --> y = z)))"
```

Here it is with the substitutions:

```
∀x. (x∈A --> (∃y. y∈B×C ∧ f(x)=y ∧ (∀z. (z∈B×C ∧ f(x)=z) --> y = z)))
```

In HOL, `f(x) = f x`, and so `f` is implicitly, universally quantified. If this is the case, then it's not first-order.

Really, I should dig deep to recall what I was taught, that `f(x)=y` means:

```
(x,f(x)) = (x,y)  which means we have to have   (x,y)∈(A, B×C)
```

which finally gets me:

```
∀x. (x∈A --> 
  (∃y. y∈B×C ∧ (x,y)∈(A,B×C) ∧ (∀z. (z∈B×C ∧ (x,z)∈(A,B×C)) --> y = z)))
```

Finally, I guess it turns out that in the context of math.stackexchange.com, it's 100% on.

Am I the only one who feels compulsive about questioning what this means in the context of Isabelle/HOL? I don't accept that everything here is defined well enough to show that it's first order.

Really, qartal, your notation should be specific to a particular logic.

## First answer

With Isabelle, I answer the question based on my interpretation of your
`f: A -> B x C`, which I take as a ZFC set, in particular a subset of the
Cartesian product `A x (B x C)`

You're sort of mixing notation from the two logics, that of ZFC
sets and that of HOL. Consequently, I might be off on what I think you're
asking.

You don't define your relation, so I keep things simple.
I define a simple ZFC function, and prove the first
part of your first condition, that `f` is a function. The second part would be
proving uniqueness. It can be seen that `f` satisfies that, so once a
formula for uniqueness is stated correctly, `auto` might easily prove it.

Please notice that the
theorem is a first-order formula. The characters `!` and `?` are ASCII
equivalents for `\<forall>` and `\<exists>`.

*(Clarifications must abound when
working with HOL. It's first-order logic if the variables are atomic. In this
case, the type of variables are `numeral`. The basic concept is there. That
I'm wrong in some detail is highly likely.)*

```
definition "A = {1,2}"
definition "B = A"
definition "C = A"
definition "f = {(1,(1,1)), (2,(1,1))}"

theorem 
  "!a. a \<in> A --> (? z. z \<in> (B × C) & (a,z) \<in> f)"
by(auto simp add: A_def B_def C_def f_def)
```

*(To completely give you an example of what you asked for, I would have to redefine my function so its bijective. Little examples can take a ton of work.)*

That's the basic idea, and the rest of proving that `f` is a function will
follow that basic pattern.

If there's a problem, it's that your `f` is a ZFC set function/relation, and
the logical infrastructure of Isabelle/HOL is set up for functions as a type.

Functions as ordered pairs, ZFC style, can be formalized in Isabelle/HOL, but
it hasn't been done in a reasonably complete way.

Generalizing it all is where the work would be. For a particular relation, as
I defined above, I can limit myself to first-order formulas, if I ignore that
the foundation, Isabelle/HOL, is, of course, higher-order logic.

Comment: I got the answer to this question in math stack exchange [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073754/flattening-quantification-over-relations). Actually I do not want to provide a concrete definition for the f, rather I would like to axiomatically specify that f is a bijective function with a first-order logic formula. Here you concretely defined values for the f and I think that is why you could prove your theroem!

Comment: No, @qartal, I could prove the theorem because I defined a set which has the properties of a function (though not bijective). Professors do that kind of thing all the time in the naive set theory portion that precedes many math classes. I didn't generalize because, as I said, I'm under the impression that nowhere in Isabelle/HOL has the groundwork been laid for functions as ordered pairs. By all means, lay the groundwork, then use that formula on math.stackexchange in such a way that guarantees it's not higher-order. I'm always willing to learn from those who know more than me.